# Adding campaign in google AdWords

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I have a problem during creating the campaign. I have test account on google Adwords. I used code from google: [AddCampaigns.java](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords_axis/src/main/java/adwords/axis/v201402/basicoperations/AddCampaigns.java)

Im getting error:

[OperationAccessDenied.ADD_OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED @ class campaignmgmt.campaign.MutateAction (ADD) requires CREATE_CAMPAIGN, OperationAccessDenied.ADD_OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED @ class campaignmgmt.campaign.MutateAction (ADD) requires CREATE_CAMPAIGN]

It occurs in line:

```
// Add campaigns.
CampaignReturnValue result = campaignService.mutate(operations);
```

I found one problem this type on a google dev webpage, however the 'solution' did not help. Anyone have any idea why is it happening?

Thank you so much and have a nice day!

Comment: Ok I found the solution, make sure you have created customer Id first (in your adwords account). Easy and simple solution, but not obvious, thought having AdWords account is enough. Thanks anyway! Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it setting the **clientCustomerId**. 
With Google AdWords Account you can manage several clients account with several campaigns.

Example of my c# code:

```
// Get the CampaignService.
CampaignService campaignService =
    (CampaignService)_user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201409.CampaignService);

// Set ClientCustomerId
campaignService.RequestHeader.clientCustomerId = myClientCustomerId;
```